# FileMaker how to rename table_name, field_name by automate script?

Tags: database, migration, rename, filemaker

I'm using FileMaker to implement my business and I have a requirement. I have so many FM files with so many tables, and fields and I want to rename table_name, field_name by automate script, not by manual using FM Pro Advanced. I've already read documents of FileMaker at https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/14/en/fm14_sql_reference.pdf and found that they doesn't support SQL script to rename table, field. So please help me any way to do it by automate script (or maybe any 3rd plugin capable, it's ok), thanks.

Comment: Schema changes cannot be scripted.

Comment: @michael.hor257k but I found that some question on filemaker community forum mention about some plugin can do that at https://community.filemaker.com/thread/75432. Have you ever used those or having any experience about that? I have so many many table & field so that i really need automate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael is correct - it is not supported.

All mentioned plugins will use FileMaker SQL/ODBC syntax, so the plugins will not solve your problem. Quick look at CNS Query (former MM Query) confirms - they do not have a function for renaming tables or columns.

The main issue is not renaming, but the reason why you have so many tables and columns, which highlight the problems in your architecture and processes.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I got it and will try another way maybe manual.